# MySQL - How to make one single SQL request for this case?

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to find a solution for the following SQL request for days, without success.

My situation:

I have 3 tables (link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BswG0.png)

- Companies, which contains companies
- Requests, which contains requests sent by companies
- Offers, which contains offers to requests submitted by companies, but also spontaneous offers submitted directly to companies

The table Offers contains 2 foreign keys:

- offers_fk_companies
- offers_fk_requests

In case the offer is linked to a request sent by a company, the field *offers_fk_requests* contains a value and the field *offers_fk_companies* is null.

In case the offer is submitted directly to a company without a request, the field *offers_fk_requests* is null and the field *offers_fk_companies* contains a value.

I would like to make a SELECT on the table Offers, to get **all entries** for offers submitted directly to companies (without any requests) but also for offers submitted following requests from companies.

I came with this request:

```
SELECT *
FROM `offers`

LEFT JOIN `requests` ON `offers_fk_requests` = requests.`id`
JOIN `companies` AS companies1 ON requests.`fk_companies` = companies1.`companies_id`

LEFT JOIN `companies` AS companies2 ON offers.`fk_companies` = companies2.`companies_id`

WHERE ...
```

I get different results when I do the request above than when I separate it into 2 differents requests:

```
SELECT *
FROM `offers`

LEFT JOIN `requests` ON `offers_fk_requests` = requests.`id`
JOIN `companies` AS companies1 ON requests.`fk_companies` = companies1.`companies_id`

WHERE ...
```

```
SELECT *
FROM `offers`

LEFT JOIN `companies` AS companies2 ON offers.`fk_companies` = companies2.`companies_id`

WHERE ...
```

Basically, there are 2 different paths: one going from table offers to table companies, and another one going from table offers to table companies but by passing through the intermediate table requests.

How can I achieve the same result with my single request than with those separate ones combined?

I can't use an UNION as the number of fields is different. I don't know where else to find a solution...

Thanks in advance.

## EDIT

It seems that, if I take my original request, and I use LEFT OUTER JOIN for all the joins, it works.

SELECT *
FROM `offers`

LEFT OUTER JOIN `requests` ON `offers_fk_requests` = requests.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `companies` AS companies1 ON requests.`fk_companies` = companies1.`companies_id`

LEFT OUTER JOIN `companies` AS companies2 ON offers.`fk_companies` = companies2.`companies_id`

WHERE ...

@Marcel: Thank you for sending me in the right direction!

Comment: Hi and welcome on Stackoverflow. This is a well prepared and complete question!

Comment: When you say you are interested in the offers, why do you want to join at all? You could select on the offers and do your filtering based on the contained foreign keys alone.

Comment: @Marcel. Thank you for your comment.

I need to get all entries matching in one single SQL request because, among other things, I need to order them according to date and because It wouldn't make sense for me to display them separately in my application. Entries have to be mixed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's comment that all should be in one go, I suggest to simply do

```
SELECT * 
FROM offers
LEFT OUTER JOIN companies ON companyId /*simplified*/
LEFT OUTER JOIN requests ON requestId /*simplified*/
```

Left outer joins only join data when there is a match, otherwise leaving the fields empty. So you end up with all offers, having the available fields filled.

However, with the current design, for those that have a request, the company data is empty. I would suggest, to set the company foreign key also on those that are based on a request, causing this key to be mandatory. Because of the request, they are tied to a company anyway.

Comment: I just tested your proposal. It works but I get, for every offer, a huge results set of unnecessary information. So, your solution is unfortunaltely not appropriate in my situation.

Comment: would it be possible to use some kind of condition in the request to have a final request which would say something like: IF fieldA is null then do request1 ELSE do request2 ? I have never used conditions in my requests, so it's all new for me and I don't even know if this is possible.

Comment: If you want to have 2 different requests, no problem. You should decide to do which in your application, not in the database though.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an UNION, missing fields can be completed with NULL.

```
SELECT *
FROM `offers`

LEFT JOIN `requests` ON `offers_fk_requests` = requests.`id`
JOIN `companies` AS companies1 ON requests.`fk_companies` = companies1.`companies_id`
UNION ALL SELECT null, null, null, `fk_companies`, `companies_id`
FROM `offers`

LEFT JOIN `companies` AS companies2 ON offers.`fk_companies` = companies2.`companies_id`
WHERE `companies_id` IS NOT NULL;
```

To get all companies_id in the same column, you can use the following query.

```
SELECT `requests`.`id` AS `requests_id`, coalesce(`requests`.`fk_companies`, `companies`.`companies_id`) AS `companies_id`
FROM `offers`

LEFT JOIN `companies` ON `offers`.`fk_companies` = `companies`.`companies_id`
LEFT JOIN `requests` ON `offers`.`offers_fk_requests` = `requests`.`id`;
```

See [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc9f92c1633ce2b9e81c5d1d8b20f957).